# Fancybox show div on close

Tags: javascript, fancybox

I'm using this code to loadup a fancybox popup, it hides another div on the parent page when it opens, then when it closes I need it to show the div again but it can't seem to find the original div to show.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox();
            $(".fancybox").click(function() {
                $("#divtotoggle").hide();
                $.fancybox.open({
                      'type': 'iframe',
                    padding : 0,
                  afterClose: function() {
                        //$("#divtotoggle",parent.document).show();
                        $("#divtotoggle").show();
                    } 
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

I get a `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null` on the `afterClose` function

I thought it's because its on the parent but `$("#divtotoggle",parent.document).show();` fails also.

Comment: Did u check , if the method afterClose() is being executed after you close the fancy box?? can you try alerting something ??

Comment: yeah I put an alert in the afterClose, and it shows the alert, but it shows it before it loads the popup which doesn't seem right, surely it should do this after the popup has been close?

Comment: You can see the fancybox documentation for more details 
http://fancybox.net/api. You are using `iframe` thus you should be using
`parent.$.fancybox.close();` , I think , I have not tested though!!

Comment: totally confused, it seems to be calling afterClose when the popup opens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not using the fancybox API in the right way: 
Try this , I have not tested it though: 
Note: If this does not work then , go to this link and tweak little bit 
http://fancybox.net/api

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    'type': 'iframe', 
    'onStart':function(){ 
      $("#divtotoggle").hide();
    },
    'onClosed': function() {
      $("#divtotoggle").show();
    }
});
```